# Exclude plugin css files from frontend assets in Grav

Tags: php, css, grav

I don't want Grav to include the form-styles.css and the login.css on the frontend assets.

Upon research i found out, that they are included to the frontend assets by the login and form plugins, which can't be disabled.

Is there a way to exclude them from being added to the assets?

Comment: If it uses `wp_enqueue_style` to do this, then you should be able to remove them again using `wp_dequeue_style`- as long as you make sure your code runs later, then the GF code that adds them in the first place.

Comment: @CBroe, I don't think this is about wp...

Comment: @passerby Gravity Forms _is_ a popular WordPress plugin ... So either that tag, or `grav`, seems to be wrong here.

Comment: @Octavia, plugins form and login cannot be disable from with Admin because they are required. When in production and not using Admin, Form or Login you can safely disable them. No css will be included.

Comment: @CBroe, Unless I'm mistaken, tag 'gravity-forms-plugin' is a misplaced tag. form-styles.css, log.css, login plugin and form plugin are clearly part of Grav

Comment: @octavia, please remove the gravity-forms-plugin tag (unless i'm mistaken)

Comment: I removed the gravity-forms-plugin tag, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @octavia, Has your question been answered? If so I'll create an answer which you can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have enqueue all your CSS assets at the end of the list with `'position': 'after'` as option:

```
{% do assets.addCss('theme://css/your-own.css', {'position': 'after'}) %}
```

Now suppose you have three your own CSS assets

Then you can remove all other CSS assets from the `assets.assets_css` array using `|slice` filter:

```
{% set assets = array_key_value('assets_css', assets.assets_css|slice(-3), assets) %}
```

This line you can add after the end of the statement `{% block stylesheets %}` and before the statement `{% block assets %}`.

So the whole scheme would be:

```
{% block stylesheets %}
...
{% endblock %}

{% set assets = array_key_value('assets_css', assets.assets_css|slice(-3), assets) %}

{% block assets %}
...
{% endblock %}
```

If you have two your own CSS, then use `|slice(-2)` and so on

Answer (score 1):

Try to use group for css

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    {% do assets.addCss('theme://css/style-1.css', { group: 'css' }) %}
    {% do assets.addCss('theme://css/style-2.css', { group: 'css' }) %}
    {% do assets.addCss('theme://css/style-3.css', { group: 'css' }) %}
{% endblock %}
{% block assets deferred %}
    {{ assets.css('css')|raw }}
{% endblock %}
```